# Client-side check if authenticated in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way in Firebase to check if you are authenticated? I could request a resource and catch the a 401 error but I'd like to avoid making the request if I already have authenticated.

Comment: Relevant docs:  [Authentication guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html), [monitoring authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication), [onAuth()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html), [getAuth()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html), and [authentication based security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Firebase reference has a way of getting the currently authenticated user.

For JavaScript you can call `.getAuth()`.

```
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData !== null) {
   // you're logged in
}
```

You can also listen for authenticate state change in realtime with `.onAuth()`:

```
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData !== null) {
    // you're logged in
  }
});
```

Comment: You can also monitor `.info/authenticated`